# Database Modelling of users table having 2 tyes of users

Tags: mysql, database, modeling, database-normalization

I am modeling a database that will hold data relating sales from a shop. I have two different kind of users which have distinct properties.

In my normalization process I created a **User1** Table and a **User2** Table.

The problem I have is tracking sales. For example if I want to track sales say for a particular kind of user for a product and know the users buying trends for that product, I would have to create two tables, **Bread1** and **Bread2** for the two types of users.

I came up with a solution but I don't know the performance implications on the long run or if its the best solution at all. The solution is having a unified table **User** which have the ID's of both users.

If there is any other better solution, I would appreciate it. 
Thanks.

Comment: why do you need to have two tables for that product? why not just have a table for the sales? i.e PRODUCT_SALES table, then have an identifier FK of the product and FK of the kind of user?

Comment: To be more specific about the distinct properties, they are more than one so i feel the performance bottleneck of having nulls in more than one field when i use one table User will be devastating on the long run.

Comment: can you post the entity relationship diagram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to have just one table for `Users` and one for `Products` and so on. You can easily categorize your users or products by making an another table for grouping them.

```
UserTypes(UserTypeId PK, ...)

Users(UserId PK, UserTypeId FK, ...)
```

Also for properties you mentioned for users or even for products, You can have a list of properties in a table and assign them by a third table to users.

```
Properties(PropertyId PK, Name)

UsersProperties(UserPropertyId PK, UserId FK, PropertyId FK, Value)
```

Comment: From your model, the properties table contains the list of different properties but does not specify their values. Even if you have Properties(PropertyId PK, Name, Value) , then each user will have a row on the properties table for a specific property. Good design though.